# Number input - text is slightly below center until you click in box

Tags: html, css

What could cause the text in a number input to be slightly below center until you click in the box?

```
<input type="number" id="txtPageNum" onchange="txtPageNumChanged(this.value);" style="height:32px;border-color:lightgrey;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-radius:5px;text-align:right;" value="1">
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue..can you create this in a codepen or something similar and link it?

Comment: here's a pen of your current code https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/gZgNoo

Comment: Thanks. Evidently, this is only happening in IE, which codepen doesn't support.

Comment: ahh.. no big deal then :)